Can we have a different scale below and above a 0 line in highcharts?
So I have a chart in highcharts, you can view it here.
I want to have the scale when below 0 to be much tighter than above 0
essentially I want the below 0 to be closer to the bottom value, rather than the 500k difference we are currently seeing.
I have tried alignTicks: false, which kind of helps a little, but not quite what we are after.
I have also tried to yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max), but it seems to ignore the min and use the same step difference above 0.
Is this at all possible with highcharts?

Could you please tell me precisely how the yAxis should look like? There are plenty of ways to manipulate the ticks and the scale. I suggest using tickPositions or tickInterval properties to experiment a bit. And pls let me know precisely how the ticks should look like below 0 and above 0, so I could help you. API references: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

@DominikChudy So above the 0 is fine, the values are formatting dynamically enough like we want, but below the 0 it is well off.  in the example above (updated with height to show better separation), our min value of a data series is -25k, the chart shows -500k, it would be good if below 0 it showed in 10k, not 500k steps

As you want the ticks look different below and above 0 I suggest using tickPositions option to set them exactly as you want. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/16sqf7L3/ Another solution could be to divide the axis to two separate ones with different scaling below and above 0.

thanks @DominikChudy. i was able to get it done with the tick positions as suggested above.  wasn't quite what I wanted, but looked a lot better than what we had before it :)

That's great to hear! Thanks for letting me know.
